# Change sequence start number

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set my sequence to use current table max Id plus one as its next value but the following command fails

```
ALTER SEQUENCE newtable_id_sec START WITH ((select max(id) from newtable) +1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL statements can't use sub-queries, but you can use [`setval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) for this:

```
select setval('newtable_id_sec', ((select max(id) from newtable));
```

The `+1` is not needed with `setval()` because `setval()` assumes the value that is passed is the last "used" value, so it will automatically continue with the next value.